# Firefox text inputs will not focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I'm pulling my hair out on this one...

Everything I read suggests it's a css issue, but I can't figure out which css is causing it.

If you visit http://demo.logzilla.pro and login (using FF of course), you will see a text input for "Messages". IN FF (I'm using v8) I cannot click-select the text input, but if I right-click it grabs focus.

This works fine in Chrome (of course).

Even if/when I completely strip the class tag and just use a plain input type text box, it still happens. I've even gone through and deleted all css imports, still nothing.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to resolve it? Is this maybe a jQuery issue? I did upgrade that recently (among a myriad of other things though...)

Comment: are there any js functions that manipulate the inputs or that id on document load or ready?

Comment: I am able to select it in FF 3.6 and FF4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the problem. In your rendered source code its line 1161 which has the line:

```
$(".column").disableSelection();
```

Which is a jquery ui function. Its probably there for a reason but i didnt look into why, you'll have a better idea than me. Perhaps find a more specific selector for what its meant to do or even just use jquery's not() to write a specific rule for missing out that specific text box.

Good Luck.

Comment: Wow, color me impressed dude. Thanks a million!